# When we run .exe manually, it works fine, but same .exe is not working in Windows's Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, exe, windows-server-2008-r2, taskscheduler

I deployed .exe in windows 2008 R2 server, it is running fine when we run manually, but it is not running in Task Scheduler (TS), when we run in TS, task is completing with out any error, but in 'Last Run result' column it shows this '(0xC0000142)' instead of 'The operation completed successfully', I checked in event viewer also no error. Please help on this.

Comment: Are you running the scheduled task as the person who ran it successfully?

Comment: No, I am configuring new .exe...

Comment: a "new exe" has nothing to do with it, a different user almost certainly does.... run the exe as the user that will run it as a scheduled task

Comment: Find the user in the General tab, Security options section, Change User or Group. Also check Run with highest privileges.

Comment: @BugFinder I am using service account, i am using it in other servers it is working fine, but in this server, its not working, you meant to say that service account needs some permission to run task in TS?

Comment: @Mahdi done those things previously, but still no luck.

Comment: @tarun92 even under you own user?

Comment: @Mahdi my account don't have RDP access to these server, I am using service account to login.....

Comment: @tarun92 go to task's properties, Actions, Edit and in Start in (optional) insert the path to your .exe file. See if it works.

Comment: @tarun92 if you're using the service account to login on the rdp session, you can run the exe to see what it does.. It could be this server is lacking something you rely on.. what does your app do? it could be this server has been hardened

Comment: @Mahdi tied that too, no luck, in 'Last Run Result' column it says 'The directory name is invalid (0x8007010B)' even though I given correct path.

Comment: @BugFinder I am using service account to run exe, app is so simple, it performs some move file functionality based on some logical condition.

Comment: Where is the directory you're trying to move to? network location, if it says the folder is wrong, did you put quotes round it?